# Gray lines on my LCD Desktop monitor

Tags: graphics-card, display, lcd, graphics

My screen sometimes becomes annoying. Gray horizontal lines occur on my screen. I've changed my Graphics Card. But nothing happened. I changed the monitor power cable and 80% of the lines disappeared :) but there's still some.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the video cable between the monitor and the computer?

Comment: Yeah. Actually, I connected the monitor to different power outlet and the problem is gone. But I can't figure it out why it's noisy when I connect the two cables on the same power outlet!

Comment: If you figured out what the problem is, can you please post a self-answer below explaining what you did? In 2 days, if there isn't a better answer by then, you can accept your own answer, indicating that the problem has been solved.

Comment: It sounds like you might have power going to a case that should not, or improper grounding. I have only read about 2 people who discovered that a ac wire was touching their case from the computer PSU. (poor Psu QC) something Like that (but mabey not that) could exist. there are ways to test for some of these thing. A simple tiny neon bulb , a voltmeter, checking the house wiring itself with simple polarity/ground testers.  Are there any items around there that would cause normal interferacnes?  You covered nothing in the question, we dont even know the connection style?

Comment: Thanks Psycogeek. I don't have any testing equipments here. I will buy a voltmeter but How should I use it? Connect one terminal to the ground and the other one to the case? And what readings should I have?

Comment: Still do not know the connection type?   Between 2 cases, there should be no AC or DC power potentials (between the metal on both connectors when the wire is not there). Understanding that the meters can slop around some when there is no connection of any type. Between ground and the case , there should be no power potentials. I did have a PSU with a grounding issue, didnt know about it, until I grounded myself somewhere else. I could feel the power. For me that is just another shock, Electricians take that stuff deadly serious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been like more than one problem :)
I eliminated the ground wire and 90% of problem was solved, then I changed the VGA cable and I got it. It's wavy-lines-free :)

Thanks guys

Comment: "Eliminated the ground wire"?  What, exactly, does that mean?  If it's what it sounds like to me, it sounds like you have a bad ground in your electrical box, and it needs to be fixed pronto. (I once had a ground lead in an outlet that was giving me ~50 volts. Baaaad news.)